# common consts methods across classes

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have 2 template classes, that share a common set of `const` methods. This suggests to factor our the code of the `const` method, to avoid code duplication.
To have a (greatly simplified) example:

```
template <class DataType>
class A {

    DataType p;

public:
    auto read() const;

// Several other methods and fields

};

template <class DataType>
class B {

    DataType p;

public:
    auto read() const;

// Several other methods and fields
// different than class A

};
```

A and B are conceptually different, and in the actual code they depend on several template parameters, so using specialization to distinguish A and B is not an option.

To avoid code duplication I see different options.

**Option 1**

Move `read` methods to a separate class, and accept a const ref to A or B as parameter

```
template <class U>
class Reader;

template <class DataType>
class A {

    DataType p;

friend class Reader<A>;
public:

// Several other methods and fields

};

template <class DataType>
class B {

    DataType p;
    friend class Reader<B>    
public:

// Several other methods and fields
// different than class A

};

template <class U>
class Reader {
  // Some data fields specific to Reader
public:
Reader(const U& data);
auto read(const U& data) const;
};
```

Cons: the syntax becomes somehow annoying, as every call to methods of `Reader` must provide a const ref to a class.
Note that the Reader class has some A/B-dependent internal fields, to be initialized in the constructor, so it cannot be a static class.

**Option 2**

Since anyway the fields of the Reader class depend on A/B, one can store a reference (perhaps better through `std::reference_wrapper`, so the class can be copied/moved etc) of the underlying data

```
template <class U>
class Reader {
  // Some data fields specific to Reader
  std::reference_wrapper<U> m_data;
public:
Reader(const U& data): m_data{data} { };
auto read() const;
};
```

**Option  3**

Since A/B must have some common structure for being used in Reader, one could factorize the common constructor in a base interface class and move the Reader methods there.

```
template <class DataType, class OtherType>
class base {
      // Some common fields
      DataType p;
public:
     auto read() const;
};

template <class DataType>
class A : public base<DataType, int> {    
public:
// Several other methods and fields

};

template <class DataType>
class B : public base<DataType, double> {
public:    
// Several other methods and fields
// different than class A

};
```

What would be the best option, and why? Are there other possibilities?

Comment: This is subjective, and depends on what kind of the interface you want to provide. (3) lets you keep the member calls, so probably that? Also (3) is reminiscent of CRTP, so if you're not familiar with it, I'd look it up.

Comment: Even though DRY is a good rule of thumb, it is not part of the constitution.  When you try to solve repetitions by adding more code than you had before, something is probably wrong. And it increases complexity, which breaks another rule. By the letter of the law, you can avoid the repetition by having `auto read()` in one class and `auto input()` in the other - "Look ma, different functions!". Sometimes using your judgement to get a well balanced code is more important than following a checklist of rules.

Comment: @PeteBecker Sure.... corrected

Comment: @BoP No, actually A/B share enough feature that the code of ```read``` is the same. That would be an exact duplication: the actual code ```read``` depends on the common template parameter(s) that both A and B have (in the example, Datatype), but otherwise it is the same for A and B. Moreover, in the actual code there are many more routines like ```read```. And yet, a lot of code in A and B differ, so that it makes sense to have them separate.

Answer (score 0):

DRY(Don't repeat yourself) isn't the only paradigm in programming, and there is also SRP(Single responsibility principle), which in my opinion, isn't less important. So option 3 definitely not the choice. Choosing between option 1 and 2, I would probably choose the second one, as in practice, users don't want to create a `Reader` class and then every time they want to `read` using it, pass the object (which in your case, was already passed in constructor).

There is a much better choice, you just need to create a `read` function with overloads for supported classes:

```
template <typename Contained>
class A { ... };

template <typename Contained> 
class B { ... };

auto read(const A& a) { ... }
auto read(const B& b) { ... }
```

In this case, you don't have to care about the lifetime of the object (in your second option, the `Reader` class doesn't own the object and just stores a reference to it).

Of course, you would probably wrap the code in a namespace as you may pollute the global namespace.

I hope that helps.

Comment: I don't see how (3) violates SRP. Inheriting interface from a template base is a common pattern, see e.g. [`std::ranges::view_interface`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/view_interface).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I don't think that A and B should be responsible for reading. I agree, that in some cases it's the only answer, but not in most

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, as stated in the question, there are several methods like ```read```. And really, the code for read(const A&) is the exactly same as read(const& B). The actual code depends on the common template parameters that A and B have, but it is otherwise identical.

Comment: @francesco then third is your way to go